ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.configs'; 'app' is not a package
My project structure is the following:
\app
 \__init__.py
 \app.py
 \configs
  \__logger.py
  \__init__.py

From app.py the LOGGER object is imported from logger.py:
from app.configs.logger import LOGGER

However when I run python app/app.py I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/app/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from app.configs.logger import LOGGER
  File "/Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/app/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from app.configs.logger import LOGGER
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.configs'; 'app' is not a package

Any suggestions?

What is you current working directory in this case? Maybe you can use from configs.logger import LOGGER.

Working directory is /Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/, why am I not able to use absolute imports?

@asant-leither so /Users/asant/Desktop/enrichment-consumer/ is what you get, when you run os.getcwd()? What is your setup, are you using vscode or pycharm? Is the project installed as pip module with the editable flag (that is what I usually do)?

Yes that's what os.getcwd() prints. I am using VSCode, the project is not installed as pip module with the editable flag

OK, I think I get the picture. If you want to use absolute imports from anywhere in the project, you will have to pip install your project as pip package. This means some setup work (setup.py, toml files etc. ) If you don't need or want that, why exactly do you want to avoid relative imports, if I may ask?

@RolandDeschain trying to fix mypy errors, using configs.logger cause mypy to give error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "configs.logger"Mypyimport-not-found

Try python app.py in the app.py existing folder

It gives the same error
